# Error en startup en API C# - Que libreria se usa para UseSqlServer

Tags: c#, api, librería

Estoy configurando el `startup` de mi API pero me genera error.

Este es el `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {"ConnectionString": "Data Source =.; Initial catalog=INVENTARIO; Integrated Security=true"},
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Tengo la cadena de conexion ahi. y en el `startup` tengo asi, pero en el metodo `ConfigureServices` me genera error el `UseSQLServer` y lo soluciono importando la libreria `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` pero se daña el `AddDbContext` y si importo la libreria `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` se arregla el `AddDbContext` pero se daña el `UseSqlServer`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

namespace apirestfull
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la linea especifica del `startup` que se daña segun use una libreria u otra:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Fíjate si donde tienes el proyecto y el proyecto de presentación tiene la misma version de Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer y Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, muy fácil confundirse con core 2.2 y core 3.1

Comment: ya lo solucione, es que a la clase context le puse el nombre `AppContext.cs`, y nunca importe el `namespace` de donde estaba la clase, y por lo visto AppContext es una palabra reservaba asi que generaba error.

Deje solo la libreria `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Gracias